# Adding New Contact with Employer

Tags: contacts

When adding a new individual with a current employer we are getting the following error:

> Error thrown
>
> Call to undefined method
> CRM_Contact_BAO_Relationship::legacyCreateMultiple()

The individual contact is created but no link to the employer. If we try to add the current employer on the contact summary screen we get the following:

> Network Error Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in
> your browser and try again.

We can add the relationship under the relationship tab.

We upgraded CiviCRM to 5.61.4 from 5.58.1 and cleared the cache. No change after that. There is nothing in the PHP logs of the CiviCRM logs. Behavior seems to be unique to this site. Nothing has changed recently.

WordPress site running Version 6.2.2

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: The site must be having custom code or extension using the function?

Comment: Did some hunting and found some custom legacy php custom files from a previous developer. Taking that out corrected the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`CRM_Contact_BAO_Relationship::legacyCreateMultiple()` was [removed last year after being deprecated](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25048) for seven years. Are you perhaps using Grant Applications? Looks like it still has to be [removed from there](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/grantapplications/-/blob/master/CRM/Grant/Form/Grant/Confirm.php#L724).

Might want to post an [issue there](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/grantapplications/-/issues) and provide a fix if you're able.